# what is "&-" mean in c++

Tags: c++, symbols

I have never seen this symbol before in c++,  how does it work?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
void print(int i){
    vector <int> a;
    while (i){
        a.push_back(i%2);
        i/=2;
    }
    for (int i=a.size()-1; i>=0; i--)
        cout<<a[i];
}
int main() {
    
    for (int i=1000; i>0; i-=(i&-i)){
        cout<<i<<' '<<int(i&i)<<' '<<int(i&-i)<<' ';
        print(i); cout<<' '; print(int(i&-i));
        cout<<'\n';
    }
    cout<<'\n';
    for (int i=5; i<=1000; i+=(i&-i)){
        cout<<i<<' '<<int(i&-i)<<' ';
        print(i); cout<<' '; print(int(i&-i));
        cout<<'\n';
    }
    return 0;
```

and it result

- 1000 1000 8 1111101000 1000
- 992 992 32 1111100000 100000
- 960 960 64 1111000000 1000000
- 896 896 128 1110000000 10000000
- 768 768 256 1100000000 100000000
- 512 512 512 1000000000 1000000000
- 
- 5 1 101 1
- 6 2 110 10
- 8 8 1000 1000
- 16 16 10000 10000
- 32 32 100000 100000
- 64 64 1000000 1000000
- 128 128 10000000 10000000
- 256 256 100000000 100000000
- 512 512 1000000000 1000000000

Comment: This is badly written, no spaces anywhere. This should read `i & -i`.

Comment: ugh.. that is? sorry about that.

Comment: In other words, `&-` is semantically *two* symbols where it appears in your example code: the bitwise "and" operator (`&`) and the arithmetic negation operator (`-``).

Comment: Negation has higher precedence, so `i&-i`, which would more clearly be written `i & -i`, is also equivalent to `i & (-i)`.  If either of those operators is unfamiliar to you, then look it up in your textbook.

Comment: oh. I thought it should be `~` ,isnt it?

Comment: `~` is *bitwise* negation.  Unary `-` is *arithmetic* negation -- the same as in `-1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression should be read as `i & (-i)`. This is a "hack" to get the value of the least significant set bit in `i`.